# Have GreaseMonkey automatically call a JavaScript function defined in a frame

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to automatically call a js function that is defined within a frame on an HTML page that I'm landing on.

Is it possible to do this in GreaseMonkey?

Answer (score 2):

```
unsafeWindow.top.frames[0].functionName();
```

But this is really VERY unsafe.
Be sure to read this beforehead: http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/network/2005/11/01/avoid-common-greasemonkey-pitfalls.html